# C# - Check if the input is an int

Tags: c#

I've looked at threads with this question. But I can't understand what's wrong. 
answerOne is the user input.

```
var answerOne = Console.Read();
        string x = answerOne;


        if (int.TryParse(x, out answerOne))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ok good");
        }
```

Error: cannot convert type 'int' to 'string'

Comment: `answerOne` is a string, int try parse needs the `out` parameter to be an int...

Comment: answerOne must be an int, of course?

Comment: Documentation is your best friend. [Take a look at the example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Which line is breaking?  `string x = answerOne` OR `if(int.TryParse`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Console.Read` returns an `int` not `string`. I guess you're looking for `Console.ReadLine`

```
var line = Console.ReadLine();
int answerOne;
if (int.TryParse(line , out answerOne))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ok good");
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`TryParse` expects an `int` for it's second parameter, not a `string`:

```
int result;
if (int.TryParse(answerOne, out result))
{
    Console.WriteLine("ok good");
}
```

Also, if you wanna take `string` as input, you should use `Console.ReadLine` method.Because `Read` only reads one `char`, and returns `int`.

Comment: Just to be clear, `answerOne` in the example would actually be `int` (`Console.Read` will return `int`). Therefore the error will be throwing on the line before the `TryParse` which makes the assignment (`string x = answerOne`). However, I am almost certain the OP wants to be using `Console.ReadLine` which would then present the problem to which this solution fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You are parsing an `int` so the `out` variable passed into `TryParse` needs to be of type `int`

```
int answer;
int.TryParse(x, out answer)
```